# Execute immediate UPDATE Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I try to make an update table `CHECK_COMPRESSER` into `PROCEDURE` and I use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` :

```
EXECUTE immediate 'update CHECK_COMPRESSER 
set NEW_SIZE_MB = '||''''||TABLE_P_ENTRY.NEW_SIZE_MB || '''' ||
 ' WHERE EXEC_ID = ' || '''' || EXEC_ID || '''' || ' AND TABLE = ' || '''' || TABLE_P_ENTRY.SEGMENT_NAME || '''' || ' AND PARTITION = ' || '''' || TABLE_P_ENTRY.PARTITION_NAME || '''';
```

dbms_output.put_line shows:

```
update CHECK_COMPRESSER set NEW_SIZE_MB = '182' WHERE EXEC_ID = '43' AND TABLE = 'MA_CONTACT_COMPRESS' AND PARTITION = 'P_OLD'
```

but there is an error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression ORA-06512: at "SASDBA.COMPRESS_TABLE",
>   line 50

so, how should I edit this code?

Comment: Why write numeric data as string literals? (E.g.  `'43'`.)

Comment: I don't see the need for dynamic SQL at all here. Why don't you use bind parameters?

Comment: Ok, how should I rewrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TABLE is a keyword. It can be used as identifier only if quoted: "TABLE".

P.S. PARTITION is the same.

Comment: Replace it to TABLE_NM and PARTITION_NM. Now, it works